# Display Columns when count from another column is greater than 1 without using joins

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2013

This is a homework related question, I'm not sure how to answer it as I'm not allowed to use joins.

I need to

Display all the columns in Vehicle for those vehicles that have 2 or more invoices.

The trouble i'm having is moving the information from Invoice to Vehicle without using joins.

Currently I have

```
SELECT Invoice.ivin AS Expr1, Vehicle.vmake, Vehicle.vyear, Vehicle.vcolor, Vehicle.vdcode, Vehicle.vfuel, Vehicle.vcylinders, Vehicle.vweight, Vehicle.vbody
FROM Vehicle INNER JOIN Invoice ON Vehicle.vvin = Invoice.ivin
GROUP BY Invoice.ivin, Vehicle.vmake, Vehicle.vyear, Vehicle.vcolor, Vehicle.vdcode, Vehicle.vfuel, Vehicle.vcylinders, Vehicle.vweight, Vehicle.vbody
HAVING (((Count(*))>1));`
```

Which does work, however i'm not allowed to use inner join. Whats a possible replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does using an `EXISTS` with a correlated subquery respect the requirements?

```
select *
  from Vehicle v
 where exists (select null
                 from Invoice i
                where i.ivin = v.vvin
               having count(*) >= 2)
```

**EDIT:** <strike>Maybe Access really wants you to have a `group by` in order to be able to use an aggregate function in the `having` clause.  Try this instead, and see if that works:</strike> I'm leaving the below query because it does work. But based on Gordon Linoff's comment below, all I needed was to adjust the `select *` in the subquery to something else like `select 1` or `select null` like I have it now above.

```
select *
  from Vehicle v
 where exists (select i.ivin
                 from Invoice i
                where i.ivin = v.vvin
                group by i.ivin
               having count(*) >= 2)
```

Comment: Which database are you using?  I can run this ok in SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned Access 2013

Comment: That's too bad. Access has a many little quirks with its implementation of SQL.  Are you able to run this SQL on its own?: `select * from Invoice having count(*) >= 2`

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly thank you very much :D I can use this to help answer the other questions I have now <3

Comment: Just use `select 1` for `exists` and `not exists`.